# Move (cut) non-duplicate rows from one sheet to another, delete duplicates

Tags: excel, vba, spreadsheet

I want to distribute information of a raw data sheet over different spreadsheets.

If value in column J matches the spreadsheet name the row can be cut to that spreadsheet in the first available row (several rows will end up in each spreadsheet). Don't move the data from raw data spreadsheet if no exact match is found (should stay in raw data file).

Furthermore it should check for duplicates based on value in column B (a unique number). If that number is in the spreadsheet where it is to be moved to, skip that line. The line can be deleted from raw data.

**Problem**: If it finds a value in column J it cannot match it still puts it in a spreadsheet (so a spreadsheet with a not matching name).
[image: printscreen (see columnJ)].

```vb
Sub DistributeData()
    Dim rawDataSheet As Worksheet
    Dim targetSheet As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim valueToMatch As String
    Dim uniqueNumber As String
    Dim targetRow As Long
    Dim duplicateFound As Boolean

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False ' Disable screen updating for better performance
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual ' Disable automatic calculations

    Set rawDataSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("RawData") ' Replace "RawData" with the name of your raw data sheet

    With rawDataSheet
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Row

        For i = 2 to lastRow Step 1 ' Loop through the rows
            valueToMatch = .Cells(i, "J").Value
            uniqueNumber = .Cells(i, "B").Value
            duplicateFound = False

            On Error Resume Next
            Set targetSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(valueToMatch)
            On Error GoTo 0

            If Not targetSheet Is Nothing Then ' If a matching sheet is found
                For targetRow = 2 To targetSheet.Cells(targetSheet.Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Row
                    If targetSheet.Cells(targetRow, "B").Value = uniqueNumber Then
                        duplicateFound = True
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next targetRow

                If Not duplicateFound Then
                    ' Cut the row to the target sheet
                    .Rows(i).Copy
                    targetSheet.Cells(targetSheet.Cells(targetSheet.Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Row + 1, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                    .Rows(i).Delete
                Else
                    ' Delete the row from the raw data sheet
                    .Rows(i).Delete
                End If
            End If
        Next i

        .UsedRange.Columns("E").NumberFormat = "General" ' Set column E format to General for numbers
        .UsedRange.Font.ColorIndex = xlAutomatic ' Reset font color to automatic
        .UsedRange.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone ' Reset background color to none
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True ' Enable screen updating
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic ' Enable automatic calculations
End Sub
```

Is this incorrect and does it still move the line?

```vb
On Error Resume Next
Set targetSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(valueToMatch)
On Error GoTo 0
```

Comment: Only thing that jumps out for me is the `.Rows(i).Delete` which could be a problem because you are starting from the top down, deleting rows then looping to the next row will cause row numbers to be incorrect. Most cases, looping from the bottom up would be better, something to look into.

Comment: You are making a newbie deletion error.  Imagine your rows are a stack of plates.  Plate 1 is at the bottom, plate 25 is at the top.  The plates are counted from the bottom To the top.  When plate 8 is removed from the stack, all plates from 9 onwards will move down and their numbers will change such that plate 9 now becomes plate 8 etc.  BUT the control variable in your loop doesn't know this has happened so when it gets incremented from 8 to 9 at the end of the loop it is effectively going to be pointing what was plate 10 (because plate 10 is now plate 9). Thus the old plate 9 is ignored.

Comment: @freeflow Rows are counted from the top down. You're analogy is reversed from my previous comment. You would have to start the counter from the last row to the first row so the row numbers are correct.

Comment: @Davesexcel. I'm not sure I understand your comment.  How the rows appear on screen is irrelevant.  The OP is accessing by index and its the index that counts (excuse the pun), i.e. 2 to last row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is rather simple. Your idea of using the following snippet

```
On Error Resume Next 
Set targetSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(valueToMatch) 
On Error GoTo 0
```

is okay. However, if there is no sheet `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(valueToMatch)` (so the statement produces a runtime error that is ignored), the variable `targetSheet` is not modified, it keeps its value.

If the variable was not used before, it will still be `Nothing`, however, if it was already holding a reference to a sheet from an earlier iteration, it will keep this reference and the following code will copy the row to the previous sheet.

All you have to do is to initialize the variable at every iteration:

```
On Error Resume Next 
Set targetSheet = Nothing
Set targetSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(valueToMatch) 
On Error GoTo 0
```

**Edit**: Didn't saw that you are deleting rows. Of course **freeflow** and **DavesExcel** are right in the comments: You need to loop backwards.

```
For i = lastRow to 2 Step -1   ' Loop backwards through the rows
```

If this is not okay (because it would add rows in the destination sheets in reverted order), loop twice. In the first loop (from `2 to lastRow`), copy the data and mark all rows that are to be deleted (eg by writing "DELETE" in col A). Then in the second loop (from `lastRow to 2 step -1`), delete those rows.